# Using TiXmlElement vector in std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector, tinyxml

While using TiXmlElement vector of tinyxml API in std::map, visual studio is giving compile time error. My code is ..

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
class childCounter 
{
public:
    childCounter(void);
    std::map<string,std::vector<TiXmlElement*>> childrenList;

    int count(const TiXmlElement&,const TiXmlAttribute*);
    ~childCounter(void);
};


int childCounter::count(const TiXmlElement& ele,const TiXmlAttribute* attr)
{
    int count = 0;

    std::map<string,std::vector<TiXmlElement*>> childList;
    std::vector<TiXmlElement*> childVector;
    TiXmlElement *ele = new TiXmlElement("ChildOne");
    childVector.push_back(ele);
    string name = "entry";
    childList[name] = childVector;

    return count;
}
```

compilation errors are

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180

Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
Error   7   error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
```

First of all i'm unable to grasp what goes wrong, but i came to knew that error is with `vector<TiXmlElement*>`. Please guide me proper direction. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated: I'm at a loss to understand why `string` is not namespace-qualified, but `std::vector` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing `#include <string>`

it's in error 1: the operator < is missing for std::string, as the tree traits are not deducable.

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  180
```